# Improving Work Flow

Tags: node.js, amazon-s3, sftp, sublimetext3

I work on a Front End Developer Team and we are looking to implement some tools to make version control and SFTP upload a smoother process. We are look for:

1. Something for Sublime 3 or 2 that will automatically update a branch on github when the file is saved.
2. Something for Sublime 3 or 2 that will automatically upload to SFTP, primarily a Amazon web server S3 bucket, when a file is saved.

I was hoping there was something maybe that we can add to Node, like an npm, or a package for Sublime. I guess this would be similar to how Stylus JS or SASS can watch files and compile them when they are saved. While I am doing my research I thought I would throw this up here to see if anyone could provide some insight.

Thanks in advance,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. For automating web-related tasks, I usually use Grunt. From a quick look at it, you could use the [grunt-github-releaser](https://www.npmjs.org/package/grunt-github-releaser). You will also need the [Grunt](https://sublime.wbond.net/packages/Grunt) package
2. On Mac OS X I am using [SSHFS](http://osxfuse.github.io/) to edit files on a remote server and you can do the same on Linux. There's also a commercial [SFTP](https://sublime.wbond.net/packages/SFTP) package for Sublime Text.

Comment: Idleberg for the win! Thanks for this. We are going to start using Grunt JS and grunt-git